# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to creade a simple CRUD web application to create and read out data. I followed some Spring Boot + Angular tutorials on the internet.

Even when I download their repositories, I get the same error again and again:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

Full debug log:
[pastebin debug log](https://pastebin.com/X4LDyfFC)

I've set up a MySQL database and also put in the data into the application.properties file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500KB

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = XXX

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Can anyone help me out with this error?

Comment: add complete stack trace of the error. Actual root cause should be something else

Comment: Can you please share that repository link here.

Comment: I think you have not created Database in mysql??

Comment: @DipakThoke it was this repo:
https://github.com/RameshMF/angular6-springboot-crud-tutorial

Comment: I've solved the problem with switching from JDK11 to 1.8.

Comment: Switching to an older JDK isn't a solution but  a workaround. Please add the fullstacktrace and your  build file (pom or gradle file) to your question so we can provide you with an actual solution.